# Workaround for anchors being broken when recreating a window?

Tags: delphi

This happens in all Delphi up to XE3:

1. Create a form and put a panel on it. Anchor the panel to `[akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom]`, but leave space between it and the borders.
2. Add a button which calls `RecreateWnd()`
3. Run the app. Resize the form so that the panel is hidden because it's less than 0 pixels in size due to anchoring. **Press the RecreateWnd button.**
4. Resize the form back and note that the panel's anchoring is broken.

As long as I can remember myself using Delphi, anchors were always impossible to use because of this. Resize the form, then dock it: the window is recreated, your layout is broken.

I wonder if there's some sort of workaround?

## Update

Two workarounds are available in the comments, one proven and stable but with form blinking, another one experimental but potentially more thorough and clean.

I'm not going to vote for either one for a while, as one of those is mine and I'm not even sure it is stable. Instead, I'll wait for some public input.

Comment: "Impossible to use" is a bit over the top I think. Plenty of use cases where the form's handle is never recreated.

Comment: I don't think so. Even when you seemingly don't do it now, a month later you do something which triggers recreate and bang, you've introduced bugs without knowing. Anchors are unpredictable.

Comment: Hmm yeah, sure, that's why they are used so much... Anchors function pretty well and have done so for me and many others for years. Apparently your mileage is different, but your inability to use them doesn't make them impossible to use for everybody else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two options I have used of which neither is really ideal for problems with the bottom and right anchors are:

1. Make the window big again before calling or causing to be called  `RecreateWnd();`, then make it small again. Has to be visible before you make it small again however.
2. Set the Form's constraints so it can't be re-sized so small that stuff ends up hidden.

An example that flashes the larger form, use height and width large values enough so the panel is not hidden:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
  OldWidth, OldHeight : integer;
begin
  OldWidth := Form1.Width;
  OldHeight := Form1.Height;
  Form1.Visible := false;
  Form1.Width := 1000;
  Form1.Height := 800;
  RecreateWnd();
  Form1.Visible := true;
  Form1.Width := OldWidth;
  Form1.Height := OldHeight;
end;
```

Comment: I wonder if using a kind of "main" panel could help in working around the flashing. I mean a panel set to `alClient` and holding *all* the contents. Then, before the recreation, you would enlarge the panel instead of the form. Some flickering might still be visible, but probably to a lesser extent than when enlarging the form.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the function which breaks everything is `UpdateAnchorRules`. `TControl` stores `FOriginalParentSize` and it's own original size in `FAnchorRules`, and uses that to auto-resize as parent resizes. `UpdateAnchorRules()` takes current parent size and current control `Width` and `Height` and saves those into `FOriginalParentSize` and `FAnchorRules`.

If everything worked properly that would have no effect during normal resizes, as the control and it's parent change size in accord.

But when the control `Width` is less than zero due to anchoring, Windows, and consequently Delphi still considers it `0`. If `UpdateAnchorRules` is called at that point, it saves wrong, out-of-accord `0` value for original width. After this the layout is beyond repair.

(If it's not called, `Width` continues to be updated in proper relation to parent `Width` due to original sizes preserved)

Turns out anything which involves creating a window handle calls `UpdateAnchorRules` twice: first in WinAPI `CreateWindow` as it dispatches `WM_SIZE` before returning (and `WM_SIZE` handler calls `UpdateAnchorRules`), and second, explicitly in `CreateHandle` after handle creation.

It would seem that as long as we can disable `UpdateAnchorRules` for the duration of `CreateHandle`, we will succeed. But there are explicit calls to `UpdateAnchorRules` in `CreateHandle`, which means someone thought there *needs* to be an adjustment of Anchor rules after handle creation.

So perhaps I'm missing something, and by disabling it something will break?

Anyway, there are two ready ways to disable `UpdateAnchorRules`: to set `FAnchorMove` or to set `csLoading`. First one is no good as there's code which clears it midway through `RecreateWnd` and then calls `UpdateAnchorRules` again.

Second one works and here's a solution:

```
type
  TComponentHack = class helper for TComponent
  public
    procedure SetCsLoading(Value: boolean);
  end;

procedure TComponentHack.SetCsLoading(Value: boolean);
var i: integer;
begin
  if Value then
    Self.FComponentState := Self.FComponentState + [csLoading]
  else
    Self.FComponentState := Self.FComponentState - [csLoading];
  for i := 0 to Self.ComponentCount-1 do
    if Self.Components[i] is TControl then
      TControl(Self.Components[i]).SetCsLoading(Value);
end;

procedure SafeRecreateWnd();
begin
  MyControl.SetCsLoading(true);
  try
    MyControl.RecreateWnd(); //or any operation which triggers it -- such as docking or making the window visible first time after RecreateWnd()
  finally
    MyControl.SetCsLoading(false);
  end;
end;
```

**Disclaimer**:

I have no idea what else will be broken by running `TControl` operations with csLoading set.

Better alternative would be to hook `UpdateAnchorRules` procedure and add another flag check specifically for this purpose, but that'd require either reimplementing `UpdateAnchorRules` completely (prone to breaking on different versions of Delphi with different original `UpdateAnchorRules`) or inventing some way to call original `UpdateAnchorRules` which is usually destroyed by rewriting it with a hook.